# If $R$ is a domain, $u$ is a unit in $R$, then does $Ru=R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone explain why? I don't understand why $Ru=R.$[image]

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Usually, a unit of a ring is simply an invertible element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly. $Ru\subseteq R$. If $x\in R$, then $x=(xu^{-1})u$. Thus, there exists $y\in R$ such that $x=yu$. Hence, $R\subseteq Ru$, and we're done.

Comment: Note that we only needed $R$ to be a unital ring and $u$ to be invertible.